# S/MIME signed mail doesnt work properly without encryption

Tags: c#, email, smime

When i check IsEncrypted flag on true, the message is encrypted and signed, but when IsEncrypted flag is on false, signing dont work.

```
       SecureMailMessage message = new SecureMailMessage()
        {
            From = new SecureMailAddress(_parameters.Sender, _parameters.Sender,  cert, cert),
            Subject = emailMessage.Subject,
            SubjectEncoding = Encoding.UTF8,
            Body = emailMessage.Body,
            BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8,
            IsBodyHtml = true,
            IsEncrypted = false,
            IsSigned = true
        };
```

Comment: Hi and welcome. Please share text, code, errors as text in code blocks, not as image. It is much more easy to read and in the end to help you.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, after some hour's of debug, I notice there is problem with body ( sended in HTML style, started with <p> ). Still trying to fix but i think problem is found and soon will be solved. When i sent some text as body value, everything works corectly.

Comment: Problem resolved. In this case when in my body message was a lot of non-ascii characters its better to not encoding it in UTF-8 but Unicode.